# Почему ошибка dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2 в данном случае?

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

Имеются логи, пытаюсь сформировать `dict` так, чтоб на выходе получить ip адрес и количество раз, которое этот ip адрес встретился в тексте.

При исполнение возникает ошибка `dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`.

***uwsgi.log:***

> 192.168.101.4 - - ...
>   192.168.102.3 - - ...
>   192.168.102.3 - - ...
>   192.168.7.46 - - ...

***parser.py:***

```py
from collection import Counter


file_path = '/../data/uwsgi.log'

x = counter('parted_row')
ip_counter = dict(['parted_row[0]'],[x])

with open(file_path, 'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    for row in f:
        parted_row = row.split(' ')
        if len(parted_row)>1:
    print(ip_counter)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, Вам нужно сканировать ip, от которых пришли запросы на сервер.
Это можно сделать без сторонних библиотек так:

```py
c = {}

with open('/../data/uwsgi.log') as f:
    for row in f:
        ip = row.split()[0]
        try:
            c[ip] += 1
        except KeyError:
            c[ip] = 1

print(c)
```

Или же с помощью `collections.Counter` вот так:

```py
import collections


c = collections.Counter()

with open('/../data/uwsgi.log') as f:
    for row in f:
        ip = row.split()[0]
        c[ip] += 1

print(c)
```

Увы, не могу понять, что делает Ваш пример кода, но ошибка возникает из-за то, что Вы передаёте функции `dict` 2 аргумента вместо 1. Подробнее о ней можете прочитать в [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict)